# Flutter iOS build/run error: widgets/context_menu_button_item.dart:49:9: Error: Type 'VoidCallback' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

I can reproduce the issue with the following simple steps:

```
flutter create ios_test
cd ios_test
flutter run
```

Versions:

```
Flutter 3.10.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 796c8ef792 (3 weeks ago) • 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
Engine • revision 45f6e00911
Tools • Dart 3.0.5 • DevTools 2.23.1
Dart SDK version: 3.0.5 (stable) (Mon Jun 12 18:31:49 2023 +0000) on "macos_arm64"

flutter -v doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.10.5 on channel stable at /Applications/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 796c8ef792 (3 weeks ago), 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 45f6e00911
    • Dart version 3.0.5
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/marku/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.66.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 14 (mobile) • A9282848-729E-41F9-BC77-591834D5DAD2 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)    • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Sometimes it gets a slightly different error (after trying to build the project in Xcode):

```
[   +2 ms] Failed to build iOS app
[        ] Error (Xcode): [ +520 ms] /Applications/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:713:1: Error: Type 'TextAffinity' not found.
           
[   +1 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
[        ] Error launching application on iPhone 14.
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 10,603ms.
```

Tried upgrading flutter packages and running `dart fix`.

Trying to compile the project in Xcode fails with different error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue related to Flutter 3.10.5 or Dart 3.0.5. When I create a new project with Flutter 3.7.12 and call `flutter run` in it, the app starts up smoothly in the simulator.